# Is it possible to specify the AWS region for the storage location?

Tags: faunadb

Not sure if this is even the correct place to ask, but I couldn't find any relevant information on this topic (apart from an old forum post that was last answered a year ago).

Like the question says, does anyone know if it's possible to specify a AWS or GCP region that FaunaDB will use?

I saw that on the Pricing page, the Business Plan offers Data locality* and Premium regions* but they are marked as future feature, with no further information like a roadmap or planned release quarter.

Many of my clients are Canadian or from Europe and they are already asking me about hosting their data in their own country. I know that AWS and Google offer data center locations in Canada (for example), so I'm just looking for any further information on this and if/when it will be possible.

I really, really don't want to have to host my own database on a private server.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi ouairz As eskwayrd mentions, it's not possible to select individual regions in which to locate your data. We do plan to provide a a set of individual replication zones across the globe which you select to control your data residency needs. For example, there would be a EU zone which would you would use for data that must stay resident to EU member states. Other zones may include, for instance, Asia, Australia, North America, etc. We are considering a Canadian zone. Please feel free to reach out to product@fauna.com for more details

Comment: Thanks for the info. I know Fauna is still being actively developed, so of course that's understandable. Looking forward to it! I'll check again in a few months

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to specify an AWS region. Fauna database transactional replication involves all deployed regions.

We are working towards the data locality feature, but is not available yet nor does it have a finalized definition.

When the data locality feature is closer to completion, we'll be able to say more.

Comment: OK, that's what I was expecting. It's not really a deal-breaker for now but many clients (esp. government and bigger companies) have that as a requirement. Thanks for the quick reply!